# OSError: HDFS connection failed (Python)

Tags: python, hdfs

I want to write to hdfs in parquet format. When connecting to hdfs with the code below, I get the error "OSError: HDFS connection failed". I'm not sure if I got the host, port and user parameters right when making this connection. How can I learn these parameters on my computer? (I'm using Linux by the way). I would be glad if you help.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
impport pyarrow.parquet as pq

file = "source_path"
target = "target_path"

hdfs = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem(host=host, port=port, user=user)
df = pd.read_csv(file)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table,target, filesystem=hdfs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to look at your HDFS configuration file (core-site.xml).
Get the value of property fs.default.name.

Should be something like:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hdfs-hostname:9000</value>
</property>
```

In your code fill the value of host to be equal to that property without the port,
and the port parameter to be filed with the number after ":"

```
hdfs = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem(host="hdfs-hostname", port=9000)
hdfs = pa.hdfs.connect()
```

If your cluster is kerberoized, you may need to kinit before run your application and pyarrow will automatically load the configuration and kerberos ticket for you.